# Change USB connection mode while on Fastboot mode

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, fastboot, usb-connection-mode

I would like to unlock the bootloader of my Huawei P8 that has Android 6.0 and is not yet rooted.

It is shown as connected to the PC when running "adb devices" before rebooting to Fastboot&Rescue mode but after that I cannot change the USB connection type so that it can be connected to the PC in order to unlock it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with changing the connection type to access fastboot mode.. Just [make sure appropriate binaries and drivers are installed](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979)..

Comment: Since upgrading to Android 6.0, every time the device re-boots, it does not retain the former option regarding the type of USB-connection and reverts to "Charge only". So,  is this not in any way interfering? Thanks.

Comment: No, it's not interfering. Whenever you boot into `fastboot` mode your device USB connection will be the needed one, you don't need to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change the USB connection type of the device due to whenever you boot into `fastboot` mode your device connection type will be the needed one.

So if your computer not recognize the device in `fastboot` mode you have driver(s) issue(s).

Try to reinstall your [phone's driver](http://www.devfiles.co/download/zygGeX8N/Huawei-MediaPad-10-FHD-USB-Drivers-TeamAndroid.zip) and [ADB](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979).